# How do i find derivative of softmax in python

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, calculus

i have trouble implementing back propogation for multi class classification of CIFAR10 dataset

**My neural network has 2 layers**

## forward propagation

X -> L1 -> L2

weights w2 is initialized as random

```
np.random.randn(L1.shape[0], X.shape[0]) * 0.01
```

X is input of size (no_features * number of examples)

```
Z1 = (w1 * x) + b1

A1 = relu(Z1)
```

L1 has ReLu activation

```
Z2 = (w2 * A1) + b2

A2 = softmax(Z1)
```

L2 has softmax activation

cost is caluclated using this equation

```
cost = -(1/m)*np.sum((Y * np.log(A2) ) + ((1 - Y)*np.log(1-A2)))
```

## back propagation

derivative of cost is calculated

```
dA2 = -(1/m)*(np.divide(Y, A2) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A2))
```

dA2 = derivative of A2

Y = one hot encoded True values

now how do i proceed from here

how do i find dZ2 (derivative of Z2) using dA2

Comment: Try asking it over at [AI Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) because Stack Overflow is for solving a specific coding problem, not mathematical problems in general. MathJax is also supported over so discussions on mathematical concepts are easier.